# Are genetic algorithms mathematically sound? If not, why are they used in industry?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, random

I was speaking to a guy with a PhD in mechanical engineering and a background in optimization and the topic of genetic algorithms came up. He dismissed them as "BS", saying that the dependence on randomness to optimize a certain situation is not mathematically sound. I am not familiar with other optimization techniques so I understand that the field of optimization is something I am highly unaware of, but this still confused me.

If genetic algorithms are not mathematically sound, why/how are they used? I saw this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genetic_algorithm_applications) on the many uses of genetic algorithms and it seems quite extensive. Is it dismissed by theorists but used in industry because it gives an *acceptable* answer efficiently / is easier to encode?

Comment: The problem is that it is difficult to actually produce random numbers. However, in most cases , pseudorandom generators do the job as well. If the numbers are actually random numbers, technically the method is not an algorihtm, but who cares if it leads quickly to very good results ?

Comment: The elliptic curve method is the best known method to find prime factors upto $40$ decimal digits size of very large numbers. This method is also based on random curves.

Comment: "Is it dismissed by theorists but used in industry because..." it's _not_ dismissed by theorists!

Comment: In computational theory, we distinguish between deterministic and probabilistic algorithms. The latter are usually far more useful in practice.